Location permission inconsistent between emulator and real device
I have a flutter app which requires a user to share their location, using the permission_handler package, I check their location, if not granted I show an information dialog informing the user we need their location to use this certain feature on the app.  Once the dialog is closed I then openAppSettings()
I then check again to see if location is granted, however, it always comes back as disabled on a real device, on the emulator is works as expected, this is my current code:
Future<bool> _isLocationEnabled() async {
    String? message;
    final status = await Permission.location.status;

    if (status.isDenied || status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      if (DeviceType.isAndroid || DeviceType.isIOS) {
        message = 'Location_Disabled_Dialog.mobileMessage'.tr();
      } else {
        message = 'Location_Disabled_Dialog.webMessage'.tr();
      }

      await _dialogService.showCustomDialog<LocationDisabledDialogData, LocationDisabledDialogData>(
        variant: DialogType.locationDisabled,
        data: LocationDisabledDialogData(
          message: message,
          confirmed: false,
        ),
      );

      final didOpen = await openAppSettings();
      return didOpen ? false : true; // Return false if settings were opened, true otherwise
    }

    if (status.isGranted) {
      // If permission is granted, proceed
      return true;
    }

    // If the status is anything else, request the permission
    final result = await Permission.location.request();
    return result.isGranted;
}

I have tried closing the app, reinstalling the app but the end result is the same always states the user has not granted location permission.
Update
This works on Android, fails to work on iOS
